# error with "pmem.c" compiling linux source code for android

Tags: android-emulator, linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling, linux-device-driver

I am compiling linux source code for android emulator. When i execute make command(for building and cross-compiling the linux source) i get the following error "pmem.c" file.

```
root@ubuntu:~/common# make
 CHK     include/linux/version.h
 CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
 SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-x86
 CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
 CHK     include/linux/compile.h
 CC      drivers/misc/pmem.o
 drivers/misc/pmem.c:441: error: conflicting types for ‘phys_mem_access_prot’
 /home/preetam/common/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h:383: note: previous declaration of         ‘phys_mem_access_prot’ was here
 drivers/misc/pmem.c: In function ‘flush_pmem_file’:
 drivers/misc/pmem.c:805: error: implicit declaration of function ‘dmac_flush_range’
 drivers/misc/pmem.c: In function ‘pmem_setup’:
 drivers/misc/pmem.c:1265: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ioremap_cached’
 drivers/misc/pmem.c:1266: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
 make[2]: *** [drivers/misc/pmem.o] Error 1 
 make[1]: *** [drivers/misc] Error 2
 make: *** [drivers] Error 2
root@ubuntu:~/common#
```

how to resolve this error. It seems that there may some problems in the "pmem.c" file and i'll have to choose different git repository. but that would be a very complex thing, as now i have already done most of the things till here. I might have to see correct version of this file. please someone tell what should i do?

how to solve this errors.

please help..thankyou!

Comment: where did you get the android kernel source code?

Comment: Your ARCH is not set to arm anymore. CROSS_COMPILE has disappeared from your command line as well. In this situtation, your build is going to fail, because you have started to build your kernel with ARCH=arm !

Anyway, you post are not really able to follow a tutorial and post a new question at every failed step without trying to think for yourself what you have been doing wrong. But what's worse, is that you don't even vote up or acknowledge the people who help you.

Comment: i am so sorry for that, but to "vote up", i should have 15 reputation points.

Comment: 1.) I am so sorry for that, but to "vote up", i should have minimum 15 reputation points!(and i tried to vote up before) 2.) And about thinking for myself, well, i think a lot and also Google many different things related to the topic. I am a beginner in android and in Linux. 3.) And also sorry for a new question at every failed step, i have very less time to work this out and need to do this as fast as possible.

Comment: and regarding the above problem, i deleted the file pmem.c from common/drivers/misc directory and also commented this statement  " # obj-$(CONFIG_ANDROID_PMEM) += pmem.o " from the makefile. and this worked!

Comment: I got the kernel source code from here, $git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/kernel/common   and from that have downloaded GOLDFISH kernel version. i am using this reference http://linuxclues.blogspot.com/2010/05/build-compile-linux-kernel-android.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in the message you pasted, both conflicting types and implicit declarations. Three things that you might want to verify:

1. did you choose the correct processor architecture (ARCH) and cross compiler definition
2. does the chosen architecture mix in files from another arch (this is difficult to check, but you can start by checking the location of the files that are mentioned in the error message)
3. check these files themselves, to see it this is a bug (very unlikely, but you never know) and that you actually have to change some code

Comment: sorry, i had not properly formated the code. Well, i got this but now there is one more error " drivers/rtc/alarm.c:16: fatal error: asm/mach/time.h: No such file or directory  ". I checked the asm directory, the time.h file is present, i don't understand what is wrong?